# explorer 11 and ogv format how to make it work?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

```
<video controls src="video/sample1.ogv"  type="video/ogg">Ici la description alternative</video>
```

working on firefox and chrome but not on explorer , what to do ?

Comment: You have to save multiple versions of the same file with different formats for browsers. That's just how it is in HTML5 video tag. @Mitch's answer is correct. If a browser does not understand a format it will check the next item in the `source src=` list... Your options are **mp4**, **webm**, **ogv**. Find a free converter software (or even try some **[online conversion](http://video.online-convert.com/)**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).

> Add it to your PATH if you use Windows

The command line to do the conversion :

```
ffmpeg -i sample1.ogv -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 sample1.mp4
```

IE11 and earlier only support this combination, so use these options.

Then add multiple sources to your video tag (as Mitch has said it):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video/sample1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/sample1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Sorry, but your browser cannot read this video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change format of file to `mp4` or other. `ogg` work well for Opera for example witch can't  use another format.

You need somethink like this

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> // for ie and other
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> // for opera and other
Your browser does not support the video tag. // for old need to put in flash player 
</video>
```

Comment: I think no. >https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . **The format is not supported in Internet Explorer in any way.

WebM is generally preferred over Ogg Theora Vorbis when available, because it provides a better compression to quality ratio and is supported in more browsers. **